# What is the advantage of a current shunt ic versus a differential ADC across the shunt?

Tags: current-measurement, differential, shunt

I'm trying to measure DC 25A across a .005 ohm shunt resistor. From my research I've found the TI INA169 which is a current shunt monitor ic. However the datasheet says it has a total output error of ~1%. At 25A, this would be .25A. I'm trying to measure to 0.01A accuracy.

With 25A through the resistor, that is 125mV. If I had a differential ADC like the ADS1115 (16-bit, 1 for sign and 15 for value), then if I had it measuring the voltage differential between the shunt would that not be a more accurate solution?

With the INA169, what is the real accuracy I could expect if I measured the output with the ADS1115 in a single ended configuration? Would it realistically be more than 1%?

Comment: One chip is an ADC, the other produces a current proportional to the input voltage differential. Two totally different applications, not sure why you try to compare them.

Comment: With the current sense amplifier chip, I would measure the output with an ADC. However with the differential ADC, I can just measure the voltage differential of the shunt resistor without the chip. I'm wondering if that is actually possible.

Comment: Instead of "throwing" a more accurate (is it really more accurate ??) component in your design, you need to think about the tolerances in the complete system. The INA169 is a **completely** different component than the ADs1115 so how can those be compared ? You should learn about tolerances and accuracies first before you can have a meaningful discussion about these. You **can** build a better than 1% setup with the INA169 if you **calibrate it**.

Comment: 0.01A accuracy over 25A is 0.04%. So, to ensure this, the first thing that comes to my mind is the tolerance of the shunt resistor. Did you actually find a 5mOhm resistor with 0.04% tolerance? I'm not sure what you want to achieve is realistic.

Comment: I've found a resistor with .1% accuracy. I'm just trying to get the best accuracy I can. What is the normal accuracy that people measure to?

Comment: You do not **need** overall 0.04% intrinsic tolerance/accuracy as long as you can **calibrate**. Also component drift can be calibrated out but when using components with a high drift (they change properties over time) you will have to calibrate more often.

Comment: There is no "normal", when I design circuits for use in an IC I have to design with components with tolerances up to 20 %. On a PCB I could have 1% resistors. An expensive bench multimeter might have a 0.01% base tolerance. There is no "normal" it depends on the circumstances and what you can afford (smaller tolerance components become exponentially more expensive).

Comment: Is there anywhere I can learn how to calculate accuracy with multiple components?

Comment: Yes: write down the tolerances for the whole chain. But again, do you want to build something that is immediately 0.04% accurate ? If yes, it will cost you a lot. **Or** will you build a setup with 5% accuracy but then calibrate it to be 0.01% accurate ?? The second is much cheaper.

Comment: The second option :). But if calibration can only remove offsets, if the reading itself is only 1% accurate how would calibration make this more accurate. Or is most of the inaccuracy due to offsets.

Comment: The 1% reading accuracy is caused by the offsets so if you calibrate these out you **can** get below the 1% accuracy. Please read: http://meettechniek.info/measurement/accuracy.html to gain an understanding

Comment: @FakeMoustache Calibration can certainly help, but at the levels required by the OP (0.01A in 5mOhm is 50µV), noise may be significant. And noise cannot be calibrated out. Design will certainly not be easy.

Comment: @dim I fully agree with this not be an easy design, certainly not something for an inexperienced person. To reduce the noise I would use filtering and/or averaging if possible (not slowing down the measurement too much).

Comment: What is your application? This will tell you what your **needed** accuracy is. Then we can work from there to see what components and techniques can deliver that accuracy. What is 'normal'? My DMM ammeter quotes about +/- 2%. If I need better than that then I am probably working in calibration standards lab, rather than asking questions on a hobby site.

Comment: There is another way to do current sensing. You can use a DC-rated hall effect sensor. One example is the ACS714. This helps mitigate the power dissipation problem with your shunt.

Answer (score 1):

The advantage to the INA169 is that it can measure current on the high side of the voltage, 30 or 40 volts above your logic level supply.  You could make a more accurate measurement with the ADC directly, but you must have a voltage that is both proportional to the current and in the 5-volt range of the ADC inputs, so you will need additional circuitry to perform this task.  It is a challenge to build this type of circuit, since all of the components will have to be at the precision you are looking for.  Remember that the shunt resistor you have chosen will dissipate 3.125 W so I agree with @dim that the sense resistor will probably not remain in this accuracy range as it heats up, and even board traces will have an effect on the measurement at this low resistance.

Comment: Also, the INA169 has bandwidth up to 100's of kHz. The ADC runs at 860 Hz in 16-bit mode or 3300 Hz in 12-bit mode. By the way, I came up with 3.125W. 25*25*0.005 = 3.125, no?

Comment: @mkeith you are correct! 3.125W